# How to identify and build a JBoss java application from 2007?

Tags: java, maven

I have a java application written in 2007-2010 that I need to build and run.
I am unable to open it in netbeans or eclipse.

Some identifying features of the source code:

- It has a maven.xml and project.xml file (not pom.xml) in root
- It has a jndi.properties, launch.properties and project.properties file in root
- it has a .project and .jupiter file in the root directory
- It is currently running in prod in a Jboss container

Are these indicators of some application framework from the late 2000s that someone can identify?

I am hoping to be able to open it in an IDE and build it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Maven 1 architecture.

- [project.xml] Project Object Model (POM) definition
- [maven.xml] Custom build scripts
- [project.properties] general build settings
- [build.properties] local build settings

Here you can see some more information and how to migrate it to Maven 2: [Maven 1 to Maven 2](http://takari.io/maven-3.3.1/guides/mini/guide-m1-m2.html)

And here is some information on Maven's website about Maven 1: [Quick start to Maven 1](https://maven.apache.org/archives/maven-1.x/start/quick-start.html)

Notice that it isn't supported anymore.

- `.project` possibly indicates it's been built with Eclipse
- `.jupiter` probably indicates that they used the [code reviewer plugin Jupiter](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jupiter-eclipse-plugin/)

All that said, I believe you could import it as an Eclipse project. Just pay attention on which Java version to use and which Eclipse and Maven as well.

I'd strongly recommend you to migrate to a newer version of Maven, but I also know how legacy software can be impacted by such migration, so it's up to you which way to go through.